# Magento 2 not display error or success message while creating customer account

Tags: magento-2.0.2, messages, magento-2.0.6, magento-2.0.7

I installed `Magento 2.0.0,Magento 2.0.6,Magento 2.0.7`,this magento2 version installed in my localhost. I have fresh installed `Magento 2.0.0,Magento 2.0.6,Magento 2.0.7` in my localhost .When I create customer an account it is not display success or error message.I do not understand why not display like this,I also clear cache and reindex but not work.In sort not working success or error message at frontend but working in backend admin panel.Any hint for that ?

**Edit:**
One thing I noticed if I login for customer at frontend or admin backend not generate `session` folder in `var/` directory.